# Error compiling fragment example using android sherlock

Tags: android

I'm using Android Sherlock, and I'm trying to implement the classic example of fragments in Android:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

But in the file **TitlesFragment.java** there's an error avoiding my app to run. I don't know why.

```
package com.android.fragmenttest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment;

public class TitlesFragment extends SherlockListFragment {
    boolean mDualPane;
    int mCurCheckPosition = 0;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // Populate list with our static array of titles.
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, Shakespeare.TITLES));

        // Check to see if we have a frame in which to embed the details
        // fragment directly in the containing UI.
        View detailsFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.details);
        mDualPane = detailsFrame != null && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore last state for checked position.
            mCurCheckPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
        }

        if (mDualPane) {
            // In dual-pane mode, the list view highlights the selected item.
            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            // Make sure our UI is in the correct state.
            showDetails(mCurCheckPosition);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putInt("curChoice", mCurCheckPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            showDetails(position);
    }

    // Helper function to show the details of a selected item, either by displaying a fragment in-place in the current UI, or starting a
    // whole new activity in which it is displayed.
    void showDetails(int index) {
        mCurCheckPosition = index;

        if (mDualPane) {
            // We can display everything in-place with fragments, so update the list to highlight the selected item and show the data.
            getListView().setItemChecked(index, true);

            // Check what fragment is currently shown, replace if needed.
            DetailsFragment details = (DetailsFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.details);
            if (details == null || details.getShownIndex() != index) {
                // Make new fragment to show this selection.
                details = DetailsFragment.newInstance(index);

                // Execute a transaction, replacing any existing fragment with this one inside the frame.
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.details, details);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.commit();
            }
        } else {
            // Otherwise we need to launch a new activity to display the dialog fragment with selected text.
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("index", index);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

The lines Eclipse is crying about are:

```
View detailsFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.details);
```

And:

```
DetailsFragment details = (DetailsFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.details);
```

And:

```
ft.replace(R.id.details, details);
```

Therefore, the **R.id.details** is the problem. The class **DetailsFragment.java** is defined below:

```
package com.android.fragmenttest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class DetailsFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    // Create a new instance of DetailsFragment, initialized to show the text at 'index'.
    public static DetailsFragment newInstance(int index) {
        DetailsFragment f = new DetailsFragment();

        // Supply index input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("index", index);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    public int getShownIndex() {
        return getArguments().getInt("index", 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            // We have different layouts, and in one of them this fragment's containing frame doesn't exist.  The fragment
            // may still be created from its saved state, but there is no reason to try to create its view hierarchy because it
            // won't be displayed.  Note this is not needed -- we could just run the code below, where we would create and return
            // the view hierarchy; it would just never be used.
            return null;
        }
        ScrollView scroller = new ScrollView(getActivity());
        TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
        int padding = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 4, getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        text.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        scroller.addView(text);
        text.setText(Shakespeare.DIALOGUE[getShownIndex()]);
        return scroller;
    }
}
```

Does anybody knows why Eclipse doesn't let this fragment example compile?

Comment: How do you expect anyone to help you, when you don't include the error log? Come on!

Comment: Sorry Ollie. That was my first topic. Thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 3):

It should be `getSherlockActivity();` and `getSupportFragmentManager();` when using **ActionbarSherlock.**

Comment: @graffiti75 Choosing this answer as the correct answer is the approach you should take instead of commenting "that's it!"